# Datatable JSON Invalid JSON response

Tags: php, json, datatables

A que se debe este error

> DataTables warning: table id=Tabla_Herramientas - Invalid JSON
>   response. For more information about this error, please see
>   http://datatables.net/tn/1

Adjunto una foto con la respuesta en mi network

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi código

```
// Call the dataTables jQuery plugin
$(document).ready(function() {
  var table = $('#Tabla_Herramientas').DataTable({

                "destroy": true,
                "processing": true,
                "ajax": {
                    "method": "POST",
                    "url": "Clases/JSON.php"
                },
                "order": [
               [0, "desc"]
              ],
                "columns": [
                {
                    "data": "Id"
                },{
                    "data": "Codigo"
                },{
                    "data": "Descripcion"
                },{
                    "data": "FechaIngreso"
                },{
                    "data": "Estado"
                },{
                    "data": "FechaAsignacion"
                },{
                    "data": "CodResponsable"
                },{
                    "data": "Nombre"
                },{
                    "data": null,
                    "defaultContent": ""

                }],

                "language": idioma_espanol
            });


});

var idioma_espanol = {    
       "sProcessing":      "Procesando...",
           "sLengthMenu":      "Mostrar _MENU_ registros",
           "sZeroRecords":     "No se encontraron resultados",
           "sEmptyTable":      "Ningún dato disponible en esta tabla",
           "sInfo":            "Mostrando registros del _START_ al _END_ de un total de _TOTAL_ registros",
           "sInfoEmpty":       "Mostrando registros del 0 al 0 de un total de 0 registros",
           "sInfoFiltered":    "(filtrado de un total de _MAX_ registros)",
           "sInfoPostFix":     "",
           "sSearch":          "Buscar:",
           "sUrl":             "",
           "sInfoThousands":   ",",
           "sLoadingRecords": "Cargando...",
           "oPaginate": {        
           "sFirst":     "Primero",
                   "sLast":      "Último",
                   "sNext":      "Siguiente",
                   "sPrevious": "Anterior"    
       },
           "oAria": {        
           "sSortAscending":   ": Activar para ordenar la columna de manera ascendente",
                   "sSortDescending": ": Activar para ordenar la columna de manera descendente"    
       }
   }

  </script>
```

JSON FILE

```
<?php



$mysqli = new mysqli(NOMBREHOST, USUARIO, PASSWORD, NOMBREBD);

$query     = "SELECT * from herramientas order by Id desc";
$resultado = $mysqli->query($query);
$tabla     = "";
while ($row = $resultado->fetch_assoc()) {
    $Codigo         = $row['Codigo'];
    $Descripcion    = $row['Descripcion'];
    $Estado         = $row['Estado'];
    $CodResponsable = $row['CodResponsable'];


    $query      = "SELECT * from herrasignada where Codigo='$Codigo'";
    $resultado2 = $mysqli->query($query);
    if ($res1 = $resultado2->fetch_assoc()) {
        $FechaAsignacion = $res1['FechaAsignacion'];
    } else {
        $FechaAsignacion = "0000-00-00";
    }

    if ($CodResponsable != NULL) {
        $sql        = "Select * from personal where Codigo=$CodResponsable";
        $resultado1 = $mysqli->query($sql);
        if ($res = $resultado1->fetch_assoc()) {
            $Nombre = $res['Nombre'];
        } else {
            $Nombre = "";
        }
    }

    $tabla .= '{"Id":"' . $row['Id'] . '","Codigo":"' . $row['Codigo'] . '","Descripcion":"' . $row['Descripcion'] . '","FechaIngreso":"' . $row['FechaIngreso'] . '","Estado":"' . $row['Estado'] . '",
"FechaAsignacion":"' . $FechaAsignacion . '","CodResponsable":"' . $CodResponsable . '","Nombre":"' . $Nombre . '"},';



}
$tabla = substr($tabla, 0, strlen($tabla) - 1);
echo '{"data":[' . $tabla . ']}';
//echo json_encode($arreglo,JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);

mysqli_free_result($resultado);
mysqli_close($mysqli);
```

Comment: Puedes agregar el JSON, algunas veces pasa eso si el JSON esta formado de manera incorrecta, puede pasar por que se trunca el String o porque le falta una coma, o cosas asi, podrias ponerlo para analizarlo?

Comment: Con cadeno el json en una variable `$tabla`

Comment: sorry ya vi, parece que ya te respondieron, en JSON todo debe llevar comillas dobles, excepto los datos numericos, pero los nombres de campos y los campos strings deben ir con doble comilla " <-- esa comilla

Comment: Porque mejor no usas `json_encode`?

Comment: @Cristina Carrasco Angulo te refiere que a los int les quite las comillas simples? ' '

Comment: Creo que si, puedes probar en la pagina https://jsonlint.com/ para validar que tu JSON siga las normas para formarlo, y las reglas para formar los json estan explicadas aqui https://www.json.org/json-es.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tienes un error en la estructura del JSON; cambia **"language": idioma_espanol** por `"language": "idioma_espanol"`.

Puedes validar tus JSON [aquí](https://jsonlint.com/)

Saludos!

Answer (score 0):

Tenía un problema parecido, con una tabla que había exportado con muchos datos.

La consulta del problema ocupaba muchas tablas y con un campo de una de ellas, me daba problema en datatable, que a pesar que devolvía bien el json,me daba el mismo error que se plantea.

Después de ver cotejamientosen BD, tablas,campos.., que si estaba con . y ñ (que si las tenía, pero en otros campos no tenía este problema); conversiones.... Al final me fije que al devolver el json parecía  bien, pero me fije que habían más espacios a la derecha en la cadena del campo problema. Así que copie el json a un editor y se visualizaron 2 enter (saltos de lineas), es decir, más de un carácter de control de termino de la cadena, por lo tanto, en el código use una función php para sacar los espacios y caracteres de control, sin tocar la BD.
Instrucción usada:

$nombre = rtrim($row['nombre_cc'], "\t\n\r");
y $nombre se reemplazaría dentro de la
$tabla .= '{"Id":"' .....................

Answer (score -1):

El problema era la codificación en la `ñ`, solo agregué:

```php
$db->exec("set names utf8");
```

En la parte de la conexión por `PDO` o (MySQL también se manda `charset='utf8'`) cuando obtengo los datos y quedó listo.